# Creating a visual user interface to receive text input using java?

Tags: java, user-interface, input, interface

I have worked with Java in the past but have never created a visual user interface, only programs that read from the command line.  I would like to create an interface that displays a box with text stating the required input on the left and on the right a blank text field that can be read from by the program.   This is for a web app I am working on at my internship, I have very little guidance and would really appreciate any help as I am completely lost at this point.  The program currently only reads line by line which is obviously unacceptable for a web app.

Thank you so much for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: Use Swing.  It is a Graphic User Interface (GUI) that is standard with Java.  A good starting point would be reading up on JFrame: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html and JComponents: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html

Comment: This type of question is considered off-topic on StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and especially read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

You can use the browser as your user interface.  Create an HTML file to create your form for the user to enter data (which they view in a browser like Google Chrome) and submit back to your app.  JSP files are the java equivalent of HTML files with optional java code inside.  Download the Eclipse IDE and the Tomcat server and run one of the tutorials for creating a web app.  Here's a link to start: https://eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html